# Remove content of list from another list

Tags: c#, .net, list

How do I remove the content of one list from another list?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
list1.RemoveAll(i => list2.Contains(i));
```

Comment: +1 altho the names `myList` and `myOtherList` are misleading in the context, as they are the exact opposite of the requested "remove ... from anotherlist"

Comment: Does this remove objects that are the same object, or object that equal each other (o1.Equals(o2))?

Answer (score 4):

```
List<object> result = anotherlist.Except(list).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a short addition and advise to James post.

If you are using `List<T>` and the `myOtherList` contains many items you should convert it to a `Hashset<T>` `var set = new Hashset(myOtherList)`, so his solution should run much faster.